# Java Gradually Decrease Number Until Target Reached Over Time

Tags: java

I am struggling a bit with a concept on how to implement some timings.

Basically, I need to write some code that will effectively perform a ramp-up to fire requests to a server.

To explain further, I need to fire requests to a server over the course of a 15 minute ramp-up period. After 15 minutes, a rate of 3 requests per second should be made. At the beginning of the ramp up period, we can start with (say) 1 request every 3 seconds. How it reaches the 3 request per second rate doesn't matter, but it should not reach this rate until 15 minutes.

What I need help with is implementing this as a timer. I need a function that will return the amount of time to wait before sending the next request.

So I have a loop like so:

- Send request
- Wait x amount of time (where x is returned by a function)

This happens until 15 minutes is reached, whereby the function always returns a value of 0.3 seconds (to achieve 3 requests per second - assumption is that requests take 0 seconds to send, but that's ok...)

The values provided are:
- Total ramp up time.
- Requests per second at the end of the ramp up time.
- Requests per second at the start of the ramp up time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * start is the moment the first request is sent (in ms)
 * end is the moment, in which the targetDelta should be reached (in ms)
 * targetDelta is the targeted period between two requests (0.3)
 * initDelta is the initial delta (1.0)
 */
private int getWaitingPeriod(long start, long end, double targetDelta, double initDelta) {
    double timePassed = (double) (System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    double progress = timePassed / (double) (end - start);
    if(progress >= 1) return (int) (targetDelta * 1000);
    return (int) ((targetDelta - (targetDelta - initDelta) * progress) * 1000);
}
```

Not tested, but is this what you are searching for?

edit: whoops, forgot converting seconds to ms.. Now tested, example:

```
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() < start + 10000) { //testing with 10 seconds

        int wait = getWaitingPeriod(start, start + 10000, 1, 0.3);
        System.out.println("waiting " + wait + "ms");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(wait);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {}

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me - just returns a value of -2147483648

Comment: i was too premature hitting the "save" button, did you test the latest edit?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit hasty in accepting the answer. I need this to continue returning 0.3 once it reaches it ad-infinitum. i.e: Once it reaches the target delta, it should keep returning that value. I have changed your loop to a while(true), but it keeps going until zero, then errors out.

Comment: Guess you could have fixed that yourself ;) Simply check, weather the 15 minutes have passed. If so, return 300ms

Comment: True...sorry. It's been a long Monday :(

Answer (score 3):

Since you are not too concerned about the exact way the rate speeds up, you could choose the following assumptions:

1. Rate will increase linearly with time
2. Some approximations and rounding of the rate is fine, as long as we don't slow down

You are starting at time=0, and going to time=15

At time=0, your rate is (say) 1 every 3 seconds. At time=15, your rate is 1 every 0.3333 seconds
The total change from 0 to 15 is (3 - 0.3333=) 2.77777

Divide this by 15, you get 0.1777777. What this means is: if your rate fell by 0.177777 every second, you could start at 3 and end up at 0.3333

This is shown on a linear graph like this:

[image]

So, if you have a method that know how long (in seconds) since the start (x), you can compute what your current rate should be.

```
double computeRate(double secondsSinceStart)
{
   return 3 * (-0.177777 *  Math.floor(secondsSinceStart));
}
```

That computation is the number of seconds you have to wait.

Using a similar principle, you can assume a non-linear curve, or tweak it in other ways.

Comment: Nice, I like this way, it's really straightforward yet powerful ! +1

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating a class that handles sending the requests if that's not already the case. Something like (this is more Object Oriented) :

```
public class RequestSender {

double startTime;

    // ramp up time is in minutes
double rampUpTime;
boolean firstRequest;
int requestPerSecBeforeTime;
int requestPerSecAfterTime;

RequestSender(double rampUpTime, int requestPerSecBeforeTime, int requestPerSecAfterTime){
    this.rampUpTime = rampUpTime;
    this.requestPerSecAfterTime = requestPerSecAfterTime;
    this.requestPerSecBeforeTime = requestPerSecAfterTime;
    firstRequest=true;
}

public void sendRequest(){
    if (firstRequest){
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        firstRequest = false;
    }
    // do stuff to send requests
}

public double getWaitTime(){
    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/60000 > rampUpTime){
        return 1/requestPerSecAfterTime;
    }
    else {
        return 1/requestPerSecBeforeTime;
    }
}
```

}

Then you can use this object in your code :

```
 RequestSender rs = new RequestSender(15, 1, 3);
 rs.sendRequest();
 Thread.wait(rs.getWaitTime());
```